# How to multiply each row in dataframe by a different column of different dataframe and get sum of all rows as a new column in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to multiply each row of a dataframe by values of a column in another dataframe ,

For example if I have the following dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'FR': [4.0405, 4.0963, 4.3149],
     'GR': [1.7246, 1.7482, 1.8519],
     'IT': [804.74, 810.01, 860.13],
     'F':  [8.4, 10.01, 60.3]},
     index=['1980-01-01', '1980-02-01', '1980-03-01'])
df_ret = df.pct_change()

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'symbol':['FR','GR','IT','F'],
                    'weight' : [0.2,0.3,0.1,0.4]})
```

I want to multiply each element of each row in df_ret to df2[‘weight’]

Then find the sum of each row and populate in a new column as df[‘port’]

I have tried:

```
df_ret.mul(df2.weight)
```

but I got a larger dataframe with all values as NaN

any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Shall we assume that the order of the columns and rows (`['FR','GR','IT','F']`) is not guaranteed to be the same?

Comment: In your question you state you want to multiply each element of `df` "to df2['weight']" but in your code attempt you are doing something with `df_ret`.  Which do you want us to use?

Comment: they should be in the same order. the real dataframe is  2000*90 one

Comment: @Bill sorry for the mistake. df_ret is correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can take advantage of index alignment by setting the index ([`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html)) of `df2` to `symbol` and multiplying `df_ret` by the newly indexed `df2['weight']` aligning Series index with `df_ret` columns. Then we can sum across the rows (`axis=1`) with [`DataFrame.sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df_ret = df_ret.mul(df2.set_index('symbol')['weight'])
df_ret['Port'] = df_ret.sum(axis=1)
```

`df_ret`:

```
                  FR        GR        IT         F      Port
1980-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN  0.000000
1980-02-01  0.002762  0.004105  0.000655  0.076667  0.084189
1980-03-01  0.010673  0.017795  0.006188  2.009590  2.044246
```

We can also set `skipna=False` if we want `NaN` in the first row instead of 0:

```
df_ret['Port'] = df_ret.sum(axis=1, skipna=False)
```

```
                  FR        GR        IT         F      Port
1980-01-01       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN       NaN
1980-02-01  0.002762  0.004105  0.000655  0.076667  0.084189
1980-03-01  0.010673  0.017795  0.006188  2.009590  2.044246
```